# Compilation Error “! Missing \endcsname inserted” The control sequence marked <to be read again> should not appear between \csname and \endcsname

Tags: pgfplotstable, compilation-error

I'm writing my first Tex-document and sometimes it freaks me out.
Trying to make a table from a .cvs-file, I'm always getting the "Missing \endcsname inserted"-error. Weird thing is that I copy-pasted this block of code from another one of my tables, that works perfectly fine. 
(Name of the file, column names, etc, are all perfectly ok.)
Anyone who sees what the problem might be? :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Optimale modelstructuur voor a, b en $\delta$ (de vertraging tussen in- en output) per meting van wildtypecellen (WT.x), mutatie 334 (334.x), mutatie 343 (343.x), onbekende types (UK.x) en telkens de hele populatie.}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/Meting/.style={column name=Meting, column type={|l}},
    columns/orde a/.style={column name=Orde a, column type={|l}},
    columns/orde b/.style={column name=Orde b, column type={|l}},
    columns/Orde $\delta$/.style={column name=Orde $\delta$, column type={|l}},
    columns/YIC/.style={column name=YIC, column type={|l}},
    columns/R$^{2}$/.style={column name=R$^{2}$, column type={|l}},
    columns/AIC/.style={column name=AIC, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{CSVfiles/Cells2.csv}
    \label{tab:Cells_Structure}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you edit your post and extend your code snippet to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with a `\documentclass` ending at `\end{document}`. This kind of error message is usualy due to a missing `\end{...}` somewhere in your document.

Comment: Done :) (Still struggling with the formatter here on stackexchange)

Comment: To be able to help you, we'll need your `cvs` file. Without it there is not much we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code still won't compile (for us) becuase we don't have access to the csv file. But the error is probably in the specification `columns/Orde $\delta$/.style`.

On the manual for `pgfplotstable` on page 11, you find the description

> `columns/{lowlevel colname}/.style={column name={TEX display column name}}`
>   Here, “lowlevel colname” refers to the column name that is present in your input table. This lowlevel
>   column name has a couple of restrictions (it has to be expandable, for example – that means many control
>   sequences are forbidden).

So I am pretty sure `Orde $\delta$` is **not** allowed as a lowlevel colname. Perhaps it would be easiest to edit your CSV file to change the column name to read  `Orde delta` for the column name in the table and change the specifications above to match. Similarly, probably using `R$^{2}$` is a bad idea for specifying the low level column-name, but there at least LaTeX is not complaining.